# How do you extract $t$ from the standard Runge-Kutta (4th) algorithm?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

About the [Runge Kutta algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)

If you have solutions $x = [x_1,\dots, x_n]$ in a computer determined by their iterations where time is incremented $t_{n+1} = t_n + h$, then how do you extract the variable time?

For example suppose the solution to a system $S$ (we make $S$ to be a standard 1st year linear ODE with initial conditions) is a linear (or at least looks like it on a plot). How would you extract the actual points $(t_i, x_i)$? The $x_i$ can be extracted easily as that is the solution to the differential equation in a system $S$, but how can we extract $t_i$?

Comment: You can't. You have to keep track of them somehow. Either you know the interval $[t_1,t_n]$) and the number of steps, or the initial point $t_1$ and the stepsize, or anything, but the values of $x_i$ alone can't give you the values of $t_i$ (well, in some cases, using the differential equation it may be possible, but don't do that).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, lets say I have information regarding: Number of steps in the entire algorithm, the initial point $t_0$, and the step size. How would I find the $i$th term $t_i$ corresponding to $x_i$?

Comment: Ah, then it's easy: $t_i=t_0+ih$ if the steps are all equal to $h$. It's not true for all RK methods: if there is stepsize adaption, the program has to give you the abscissas it chooses.

Comment: I thought the partition was $t_{i+1} = t_i + ih$. huh

Comment: That would increment $t_i$ by larger and larger values. Don't you think this would be a strange thing to do?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, ah never mind because $t_{n+1} = t_n + h$, but $t_{n} = t_{n-1} + h \implies t_{n+1} = t_{n-1} + 2h \implies t_0 + ih$

Comment: Yes, that's right (you forgot "$t_i=$" in the last step)